# Does one "douse" or "dowse" a spotlight or projector?

Tags: word-usage, confusables

A recent SMS conversation has prompted me to question my use of "dowse", "dowsing", and so on in relation to lighting instruments and projection equipment. I do not remember from where I got this habit, but I do know that I've had it a while.

I looked up "dowse" [in Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dowse), though, and there is no mention whatsoever of anything related to extinguishing or putting out. [Merriam-Webster says](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dowse) it's a variant of "douse", though, and [Google says](https://www.google.com/search?q=dowse) that "douse" is a synonym—but Thesaurus.com [doesn't even know](http://thesaurus.com/browse/dowse) the word "dowse", and other sites I've looked at make no mention of it in their synonym lists for "douse".

I guess I've confused myself through research at this point. It seems like the more unusual word "dowse" would fit in a theatrical or film production context, where jargon is extremely common (I should know), but I do want to make sure I'm using the word correctly.

Comment: I really wouldn’t put anything into what Wiktionary may or may not say if I were you.  For the full answer, you just have to look at (higher-)quality dictionaries; see my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Dowsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowsing) means divination of underground resources (water, oil, buried treasure, etc.), usually by means of a forked stick.  I rarely if ever hear about it here in Los Angeles, but when I lived up in the hills, our neighbor had the reputation of being an excellent "water witcher".

**Dowse** is given as an alternate spelling of [**douse**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/douse?s=t) (to put out or extinguish, as fire or hope) in several dictionaries, as @tchrist has pointed out - but in 21st-century usage, it is highly unusual.

Comment: By the way - my parents and I had **very** different reactions to our neighbor's dowsing:  my reaction was "what a load of superstitious BS", while their reaction was "that man is playing with Powers Beyond His Control!  Thou shalt not suffer a witch to live!, etc. etc."  Takes all kinds to make a world, no?

Comment: Pardon me, but who is it who says that *dowse* is not a generally accepted alternate spelling of *douse*? Do you have an actual source you can cite for that assertion, or is it merely your personal opinion?  Please see my answer for details and variants.

Comment: @tchrist - In the citations you give for your answer, did you notice the little number "16" - as in "Forms: Also 16 dousse, dowsse, douze, 16– dowse, douce."?  That 16 means "attributed circa 1600".  If you can find me some published examples from the 20th or 21st century where "dowse" is used to mean anything besides water-witching or someone's last name, I will concede your point.  Otherwise not.  (Interesting sidenote turned up while I was looking for examples: "dowse", meaning a heavy blow to the face, was attributed {perhaps apocryphally} to a famous brawler whose last name was Dowse.)

Comment: @MT_Head, Dictionary.com also says *dowse* can be an alternate spelling of *douse*.

Comment: What you describe is for `16` by itself, but when they write `16–` they mean from that point onwards ***up through the present day***. For example, there’s an 1872 citation that uses the *dowse* spelling for **douse**, *v.²*, which I believe to be the operative definition here: “1872   R. Browning *Fifine* lxv,  — Sowse Underneath ducks the soul, her truthward yearnings dowse Deeper in falsehood!” is the full citation.

Comment: @tchrist, that sounds like the divining (i.e. usual) definition of *dowse* to me.

Comment: @Marthaª You may be right. However, if that were so, it would antedate by 15 years the first given reference for **dowse**  *v.*  The Robert Browning citation is given under **douse** *v.2* sense 3, the intransitive one for plunging into water. They haven’t updated it since *OED2* though, so I am anxious to see what they will do with that entry.

Comment: [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) gives 10 results (1990-2011) for "dowse".  5 are about a sports coach named David Dowse; 1 is a reference to divination; 4 are used to mean "soak" or "splash".  The same period gives 252 results for "douse".  It still seems pretty thin to me (one of those four, the story from F&SF, looks like the editor was out to lunch) but I'll reword my answer to "highly nonstandard alternate."

Comment: The [BNC](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/) also gives 10 results (for the 1980s and early 90s); four are last names, four are divination, and two mean "extinguish".  In the same period, "douse" gets 41 uses. (Strangely, at least one of those is an odd spelling of the French word for "twelve".)

Comment: @MT_Head So you’re saying that the BNC results from that period have twice as many uses of *dowse* for divination as they have for extinguishing?  You can’t really tell anything too terribly precise or definitive from such small numbers, I think, but 2:1 is a lot different from 50:1 in my book.

Comment: @tchrist - I'm saying that, despite the fact that "divining for water" is a pretty exotic topic and "extinguishing, soaking, etc" is relatively common, "dowse" still means the former more often than the latter.  The significant numbers, I think, are the ratios ("douse":"dowse") of 252:4 for the COCA and 40:2 for BNC.  _Those_ numbers are what lead me to call it an uncommon spelling.

Comment: @MT_Head Agreed.

Comment: If anyone still isn't convinced of MT_Head's position here, have a look at [The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=z_VmtjAU01YC&pg=PA111&dq=douse+dowse&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H1P6U9b_JMia1AWU8YCgAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=douse%20dowse&f=false). Their entry for **douse;dowse** leaves no doubt as to what *they* consider "correct usage". They make the specific point that using *dowse* instead of *douse* is more common than using *douse* instead of *dowse*, but fail to mention this might be because one *meaning* is much more common than the other.

Answer (score 3):

Per the *OED*, *dowse* is a variant spelling of both *douse* verbs.  They do not know where the water-seeking verb came from.  I’ll give the nouns first.

> #### [dowse, *n.¹*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57137) [*a* 1627]
>
> **Pronunciation**:    /daʊs/
>   **Forms**:  Also 16 **douze**, 16– **douce**, **dowse**, 18 **douss**.
>   **Etymology**:  < **douse** *v.¹*
>        A dull heavy blow or stroke.

---

> #### [† douse | dowse, *n.²*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57138) [*c* 1325 / *a* 1500]
>
> **Etymology**:  perhaps subst. use of *douse*, **douce** *adj*. sweet.
>  
>   *Obs.*
>       A sweetheart; a ‘dear’. Also *ironical*.

---

> #### [douse, *v.¹*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57140) [1559]
>
> **Pronunciation**:  /daʊs/
>   **Forms**:  Also 16– **dowse**, 17 **dousse**.
>  
>   **Etymology**:  Of obscure origin: known only from 16th cent. In sense 1, perhaps related to Middle Dutch *dossen*, or early modern Dutch *doesen* to beat with force and noise (Kilian): compare also East Frisian *dossen* to beat, strike, punch, knock, and German dialect *dusen*, *tusen*, *tausen*, etc. to beat, strike, butt (Grimm). Senses 2, 3 may be the same word; compare ‘to strike sail’; sense 4 is more doubtful, and may be distinct. All the senses belong to the lower strata of the language.
>
> 1. †  *trans*. To strike, punch, inflict a blow upon.
> 2. *Naut*. To strike (a sail); to lower or slacken suddenly or in haste; to close (a port-hole).
> 3. To put off, doff.
> 4. To put out, extinguish, dout (a light).
> 5. To throw down, table (money): = **doss** *v*.¹ 2.
> 6. To ‘shut up’, stop, cease.

---

> #### [douse, *v.²*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57140) [1600]
>
> **Pronunciation**:   /daʊs/
>  
>   **Forms**:  Also 16 **dousse**, **dowsse**, **douze**, 16– **dowse**, **douce**.
>  
>   **Etymology**:  Appears c1600: origin unknown; perhaps onomatopoeic; compare *souse*. <sup><sub>It is of course not impossible that it arose out of **douse** *v*.¹, though connection is not obvious.</sub></sup>
>
> 1. † *trans*. To plunge vigorously *in* water, or the like; to immerse with force. *Obs*.
> 2. To throw water over; to water, to drench.
> 3. *intr*. To plunge or be plunged into water.

---

> #### [dowse, *v.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57322) [1894]
>
> **Pronunciation**:   /daʊz/
>   **Forms**:  Also **dowze**, **douse**.
>  
>   **Etymology**:  Derivation unknown; apparently a dialect term.
>  
>       *intr*. To use the divining- or dowsing-rod in search of subterraneous supplies of water or mineral veins.
>  
>   **Derivatives** 
>     • **dowsing** *n.*
>     • **dowser** *n.* /ˈdaʊzə(r)/ one who uses the divining-rod, a water-diviner.
>     • **dowsing-rod** *n.* the rod or twig used by dowsers.

All these entries are from the online 3<sup>rd</sup> edition of the *Oxford English Dictionary*, but also appeared in the 2<sup>nd</sup> edition  from 1989, with an earlier version also appearing in the *New English Dictionary* (that is, the 1<sup>st</sup> edition) of 1897.

Comment: I'm getting lost in the OED's abbreviations and formatting conventions. Could you maybe remove the obsolete definitions and the irrelevant pronunciations and derivatives?

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if that pesky pond (aka Atlantic ocean) is interfering again: the OED seems to imply that *douse* is a lower-class version of *dout*, but every American dictionary I checked, as well as my own experience, says that *douse* is the current word and *dout* is obsolete at best.

Comment: @Marthaª Thank you for the formatting help. I don’t want to delete anything, because I don’t know that it is *not* relevant. If you are looking at verb-1, it has a bunch of odd senses to it, including sense 3 meaning *doff*, sense 4 meaning *dout* (not a word I use), and sense 5 meaning *doss*. Those may be red herrings, as it’s the verb-2 that means the immerse in water sense. But one might argue that there should be only one entry with a bunch of senses, or even more than two entries yet with fewer senses. It’s really unclear.  Ask me about abbreviations and I’ll explain.

Answer (score 3):

I've operated a spot lamp in theaters a number of times here on the California side of whatever pond you choose, and if you want to extinguish the light, you "douse" it using the chopper blades, which are operated by a lever, or stick, if you will.

Any reference manual for a spot lamp will use the term "douse" to mean to dim or fully extinguish the light from the lamp.

Here's an example for a well-known brand of spot lamp...

https://www.brockport.edu/theatre/Trouperette3.pdf

I've always thought that the action of dousing a light, as well as the searching for water variant "dowse", referred to the actual act of dipping a stick 'down', either to put out the flame at the end of a torch, or moving a lever to throw a cover over the spotlamp beam, or twitching a stick as you stumble around searching for water or minerals.

The last time I saw anyone 'dowse' for something, it was a septic tank repair man at my in-law's house in the mountains of Southern California. He was unable to locate the main drain line and cap over the tank precisely, and I kept sighting along the six inches or so of drain line that was just visible above ground near the house, pointing off to the north and down the hill where he was dowsing, and I kept telling him "just dig along this line" and pointing, and that's how he finally found the tank.

It was interesting to watch him wander around the property with two bent wires rolling between his fingers, but I saved him (and my in-laws) at least a half-hour just using my knowledge that pipes are often manufactured as straight tubes.  : )

Answer (score 0):

Webster's 1913:

> [Douse](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=douse&quicksearch=on&sourceid=Mozilla-search), v. t. [AS. dwæscan. (Skeat.)] To put out; to extinguish. [Slang] To douse the glim." Sir W. Scott.

No such slang meaning is attributed to [dowse](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=dowse&quicksearch=on&sourceid=Mozilla-search).

[Ngram viewer shows](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=douse%20the%20glim&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=0) Scott's "douse the glim" in use from 1831 onward: 
[image]